# Blockchain consensus without having all blocks in each node

Tags: java, p2p, bitcoin, blockchain, consensus

I was wondering if the nodes that form a blockchain can reach consensus just having part of the contents of the blockchain. I mean, actual implementations of blockchains assume that every node contains the entire blockchain, that way they can validate transactions without needing anyone else, and my question is: Is there any way that they can validate a transaction if they just have part of the blockchain, not all blocks? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not with 'part' of the Blockchain... but yes using something called 'Snapshots' which is like the relevant state of the blockchain at a given point in time. This isn't fully implemented in many protocols yet, but is possible and I believe is used by a couple

Answer (score -1):

No because each node can potentially do a malicious attack like a double use of the same transaction.
I will show this by a practical example: i owe 2 bitcoin by transaction A and I want to use my 2 bitcoin twice, so i want to make a transaction to you called transaction B and a transaction to another guy called transaction C.
If your node and node miners have only part of the transaction they could validate the coin passage A -> B and also the coin passage A -> C. And this will be a corruption of the whole blockchain.

Also if I've not the block A in my blockchain how can I trust the validity of your data (coins)? You could've generated and sent this block (like printing false money in real life).